# how do you delete a row, if this has foreign keys? sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

for example if you have this rows

```
create table table1 
(
column1 int primary key,
column2 varchar(50),
column3 varchar(50),
column4 varchar(50),
)

create table tabla2
(
col1 int primary key,
col2 int,
col3 varchar(50),
foreign key(col2) references table1(column1)
)
```

and for example i have a row

```
insert into table1(column1,column2,column3,column4) values (1,'a','b','c');

insert into table2(col1,col2,col3) values (1,1,'xxx');
```

and i want to delete all these rows (just them)

```
delete from table1 where colum1=1;
```

doesn't work,

i know i can first delete the another and after it, but i have a database with a lot of tables
and they have a foreign key since another table, and i want to delete the row, for all rows are relationed with this, delete too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreign key(col2) references table1(column1) on delete cascade
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

Add [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to your foreign key constraint.

Comment: how is it? i've never listened about it

Comment: `foreign key(col2) references table1(column1) on delete cascade`

Comment: isn't there any another form easy? for i dont edit database i friend told with a code, delete all rows relationed i dont know what is the code @domsterr